# Laravel 4 Auth redirect always to login page? /login

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using laravel for my web application and in routes.php I have:

```
// admin routes
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
Route::controller('admin', 'UsersController');
});
```

I want to protect and check if the person is logged in , but this code always redirect to "/login" i want it to redirect to "admin/login" , can this be done?

Comment: look at the code in your `filters.php` file for the `auth` filter. You can redirect there if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 13):

There is a default `auth` filter in the `filters.php` file, it should be like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route, $request)
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login'); // /login url
});
```

This filter (given above) will check if the user is not logged in then a redirect will occur and user will be sent to `/login` `url` and otherwise nothing will happen, user will be sent to the requested page.

Also, following `filter` is available by default and this `filter` just checks if the user is already logged in then (s)he will be redirected to `/` (home page)  by default:

```
Route::filter('guest', function($route)
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/'); // you may change it to /admin or so
});
```

This (`guest`) filter is used with `/login` as given below, so if a logged in user intended to log in then the user will be redirected to home page by default:

```
Route::get('login', array('before' => 'guest', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getLogin'));
```

Now, in your `routes.php` file you have following route declared:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::controller('admin', 'UsersController');
});
```

If everything is fine then this setup should work. If a logged out user tries to visit `admin` then user will be sent to `login` and these are by default available and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add the following filter:

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('admin/login');
});
```

I copied original `auth` filter delivered with Laravel.

Next, use your new filter:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.admin'), function()
{
Route::controller('admin', 'UsersController');
});
```

Comment: If you have getLogin() in UsersController, then it's understandable. Add it as a separate route.

Comment: yes I have getLogin() in UsersController , what you mean separate route?

Comment: I mean `Route::get('admin/login', function() {...});` or separate controller for authentication jobs.

Comment: if users are not Auth and they go to admin or admin/login , both will go to admin/login , do I have to create two Routes functions?

Comment: For /admin you can have getIndex() method in your controller. As you can see, you can't have this filter applied to admin/login path, because it creates the loop. That's why I suggest you to put it in separate place.

Comment: I see your point but when I create Route::get('admin/login', function()
{  }); how do I show the admin.layout template? its not showing ?

Comment: I have the layout defined in UsersController ,

Comment: `return View::make('...');`

Comment: yes but in my UsersController I have this : protected $layout = "admin.layout";

Comment: I'll say it again: the point is to make admin/login path independent from your controller, so it doesn't matter what you have there.

Comment: yes its working , but its not showing my main admin.layout template when you go to admin/login

Comment: it doesnt really work , now if you try to login it always redirect to admin/login no matter what??

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution:

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function() {
    // if not logged in redirect to the login page
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('admin/login');
});
Route::filter('auth.login', function() {
    // if already logged in don't show login page again
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('admin');
});

Route::get('admin/login', ['before' => 'auth.login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getLogin']);

Route::group(['before' => 'auth.admin'], function () {
    Route::controller('admin', 'UsersController');
});
```

Comment: is this in my filter.php file?