# How do I redirect Auth Login to on Admin/Login page?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel's built in auth system.I have a page for admin login  on admin/login.If I entered wrong username and password it redirects me to default auth/login instead of admin/login with erros.How do I fix it?

I want normal users to login via auth/login and admin via admin/login

How do I do that?

Comment: Just check if user is admin and then redirect him to admin panel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 Auth redirect always to login page? /login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948948/laravel-4-auth-redirect-always-to-login-page-login)

Comment: I want the solution for Laravel 5

Comment: It's almost the same please read the docs

Comment: I did.I don't want to create a custom auth like the doc says.I want to use of  Laravel's own Auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using laravel 5, and the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait on the controller that is a handling your admin login, you can set the `$loginPath` property on your controller to override the default login path (which is - as you say, `'auth/login'`).

```
class AdminAuthController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Override login path property
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $loginPath = 'admin/login';

}
```

You can add a similar `$redirectPath` property to change the default redirect path for a successful login. (This defaults to `/home`)

NB - this requires you to be using a different controller for your normal user and admin logins

Comment: I'm getting an error when I posting it to the controller

ErrorException in Route.php line 194: Undefined offset: 1


Can you help me?

Comment: can you post your controller, and how you've registered your controller (presumably something similar to `Route::controller( App\AdminController::class )` or `Route::controller( 'App\AdminController' )` )

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.3 the you can change your redirect if not logged in (unauthenticated) from App/Exceptions/Handler.php

In your case, change in unauthenticated method:

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

to

```
return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
```